# MongoRepository Compared two column + Spring Data

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mongorepository

I would like to execute the query with compared two column value using mongorepository + spring data (HQL or criteria query). I am showing you relation query and i want to convert to mongo.

> Select * from Employee em where em.limit < em.age

I want to convert above query to HQL query using Spring data.

Comment: You can't use HQL with Spring Data MongoDB beacause you are not using Hibernate with MongoDB...

Comment: @davioooh : i am using spring data (jpa repository) with mongo so i can used, even i am using it. the question is i want the same form in mongo query. For reference https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/

Comment: Are you using `JpaRepository` as `CrudRepository` with Mongo or `MongoRepository`?

Comment: You can try `Query query = new Query();` Here Query is from `org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository` package and then you can write criteria query like `query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("this.limit > this.age");` Finally, `mongoOperation.find(query, Employee.class);`. Hope this helps!

Comment: I am using MongoRepository . Let me try above one

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$where` to achive this:

```
db.employee.find( { $where: "this. limit < this. age" } );
```

check out the document here:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/

Comment: That is native query. I want HQL form as i am using Spring data with Mongo + jpa. https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/

Comment: @BhargavPatel then query it with `mongoTemplate`, spring doesn't support this.